# WebM packet headers for real time streaming

Tags: c++, video-streaming, html5-video, webm

I need to stream webm video to browser from my video server.
The video server (C++) receives vp8 encoded frame packets of webcam or screen from the client with .ivf headers like `<4_bytes_data_size><8_bytes_pts><vp8_encoded_data>`. Also I send 4 bytes of total packet duration before the rest of data, so the server knows the presentation timestamp, size and duration of each frame.

The question is: **which headers should I use for frames in order for the browser to be able to play the stream in the `<video>` tag. Maybe there is some standard for webm real time streaming implementing?**

*PS: AFAIK the webm consists of EBML markup. If the same is used in `<video>` tag to parse the stream, could someone explain me what are the minimal set of EBML elements for video playback (no audio, just video)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video tag does not support ivf. Minimum webm requirement is whatever the minimum is to package your stream.